# detach with custom attribute as input in pivot table in laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel-4

I had tried attaching a custom column value in pivot table but is there any way to detach giving a where condition with custom column value in laravel 4.1?

```
#User Model
public function pass() {
     return $this->belongsToMany('Test')->withPivot('action')->withTimestamps();
}
#Test Model
public function pass() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot('action')->withTimestamps();
}

Attach :
$user->pass()->attach(10, array('action' => 1)); # this works fine

Detach :
$user->pass()->detach(10, array('action' => 1)); # deletes all entries irrespective of action value !
```

Any thoughts

Comment: I have a similar situation. I'm struggling to attach/detach based on additional pivot columns.

Answer (score 1):

This may work but might depend on whether your action has it's own model:

```
$user->pass()->newPivotStatementForId($pass->id)->whereActionId($action->id)->delete();
```

Or perhaps:

```
$user->pass()->newPivotStatementForId($pass->id)->whereAction($action_id)->delete();
```